# How to start a Timer which executes regularly but for a fixed period of time

Tags: java, timer, future, timertask

I am developing a system which has to start a task (download a file) regularly every N seconds. This is not a problem I did it using `Timer`and `Timertask`as follows:

```
FileTimer rXMLFileTimer;

private static Timer timer = new Timer("FileReader");
rXMLFileTimer = new ReadFileTimer();
int myDelay = 30;
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(rXMLFileTimer, 0, myDelay * 1000);
```

and the `timertask` will run until `rXMLFileTimer.cancel()` is called. Up to now no problem.

Now, It has been required that this `timertask` should run until the `rXMLFileTimer.cancel()` is called **or** a given amount of time.

My first approach (which didn't work) was to implement a `Future`as follows:

```
public class Test {

public static class MyJob implements Callable<ReadFileTimer> {

    @Override
    public ReadFileTimer call() throws Exception {
        Timer timer = new Timer("test");

        ReadFileTimer t = new ReadFileTimer();

        int delay = 10;
        // Delay in seconds
        timer.schedule(t, 0, delay * 1000);

        return t;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyJob job = new MyJob();
    System.out.println(new Date());

    Future<ReadFileTimer> control = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(job);

    ReadFileTimer timerTask = null;
    try {
        int maxAmountOfTime = 30;
        timerTask = control.get(maxAmountOfTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
        control.cancel(true);           
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {}

    }
}
```

This is not working because I cannot call `timerTask.cancel()` after the timeout has happen. Then my question is: How can I start a `timerTask`for a given amount of time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just throw in a second timer task to cancel the first? For example, this code prints the date every second for ten seconds:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    final TimerTask runUntilCancelledTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(new Date());
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(runUntilCancelledTask, 0, 1000);
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runUntilCancelledTask.cancel();
        }
    }, 10000); // Run once after delay to cancel the first task
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty much easier than what I was trying